# Error Read from .h5 file by pandas python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I'm trying to read data from .h5 file by using pandas in jupyter python but I got errors.

In .h5 file, there are two kinds of type, "timestamp : compound/Vdta", "data : 16-bit integer"

[image]

But pandas only recognized timestamp after "store" from .h5 file.

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'C://HDF/test.h5'
store = pd.HDFStore(filename)
print (store.is_open)
>> True
print (store)
>> <bound method HDFStore.open of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
>> File path: C://5G/HDF/case_6.h5
>> BFN/timestamp                                              frame_table [0.0.0] (typ->generic,nrows->409,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[core,epoch]
```

Is there any idea to read "data" in pandas?

Comment: Try this `hdf5_file = pd.read_hdf(filename)` and after that read the objects stored

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried your way but I got errors, `HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5Dio.c", line 173, in H5Dread
    can't read data
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5Dio.c", line 437, in H5D__read
    src and dest data spaces have different sizes

End of HDF5 error back trace

Problems reading records.` Do you have any idea?.